# PHP + cURL gets file that shouldn't exist

Tags: php, curl

This is my first question on here and I wouldn't ask if I haven't tried nearly everything in my might already. My problem is as follows:

I got tasked to maintain an old webapp in our company and part of it was to change an old date in a html file to the current year. I did that and when I access the file with the required parameters directly it works. Now the app itself doesn't access this file directly but loads it in through something they called "proxy.php" - it defines allowed hosts and some other stuff but the thing it mostly does is get data via cURL. If I access the file that I changed through the "proxy.php" it returns a file that shouldn't exist anywhere on the server (with old content in it).

I replicated proxy.php's function down below with the same result (an old file is served):

```
<?php 
//phpinfo();
//Proxy.php test because weird things are happening...
$url = $_GET["url"]; //The url that it gets is escaped already.

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);

$xml = curl_exec ($ch);


echo $xml;

?>
```

I also got told by a colleague that they always only altered they date in the html file and it worked until now. I hope I provided enough information about my problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you add required querystring parameters also?

Comment: Yes the parameters are correct. Upon opening the file directly everything works. But opening the file through cURL (again with all the required parameters) it serves an old file.

Comment: Check it in postman, if you get a correct content in postman,  use code generator to generate code for php in postman. Check the difference.

Comment: Got the same result using postman.

Comment: Same result with "file_get_contents" btw

Comment: Looks like you modified some other place. May be check if you modified the correct code

Comment: No it should be the correct file that I modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to give a quick update as I have resolved the issue thankfully.

Deep in the configuration was an old proxy server that seemed to be serving cached files.

I changed the "proxy.php" to use a new proxy server:

```
$proxy = "your.proxy.server:port";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
```

Thanks everyone for your advice :)